# how to use newAudioClip outside of an applet?

Tags: java, audio, applet, jframe, javasound

I want to do something like this:

```
    java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(songPath);
```

But however, the application i want to do it within is a JFrame. So, anyone got a way to use it without extending Applet?

Comment: *"..anyone got a way to use it without extending Applet?"*  Well if by 'use it' you mean play a clip, only since 1.3+.  See the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for working source.

Answer (score 0):

To Play a clip (From the [Javasound tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info)):

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            "http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(Source: [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461237/how-to-use-newaudioclip-outside-of-an-applet/27017944#comment27132508_18461237))